# How do you create an inception module in tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

Looking at the tensorflow page: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception

They show an image with their architecture, specifically their 'inception' modules which contain in parallel:

- conv layer of 1x1
- conv layer of 3x3
- conv layer of 5x5
- ave pooling + 1x1 conv

Followed by an 'concat' layer.

[image]

How can I create this in tensorflow?

I figured I could do something along the lines of this to create the parallel operations:

```
start_layer = input_data

filter = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1,1,channels,filter_count], stddev=0.1)
one_by_one = tf.nn.conv2d(start_layer, filter, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')

filter = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3,3,channels,filter_count], stddev=0.1)
three_by_three = tf.nn.conv2d(start_layer, filter, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')

filter = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5,5,channels,filter_count], stddev=0.1)
five_by_five = tf.nn.conv2d(start_layer, filter, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')

filter = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1,1,channels,filter_count], stddev=0.1)
pooling = tf.nn.avg_pool(start_layer, filter, strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='SAME')

filter = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1,1,channels,filter_count], stddev=0.1)
pooling = tf.nn.conv2d(pooling, filter, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')

#connect one_by_one, three_by_three, five_by_five, pooling into an concat layer
```

But how do I combine the 4 operations into an concat layer?

Comment: the result of all your inner model should have the same dimension then you just have to concatenate then in one tensor. I'm not sure about tensorflow but you can numpy to arrange the input for the next layer.

Comment: someone has implemented an inception module from scratch https://hackathonprojects.wordpress.com/2016/09/25/inception-modules-explained-and-implemented/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did something very similar to what you did, and then finished it off with `tf.concat()`. Note the `axis=3` which matches my 4d tensors and concats to the 4th dimension (index 3).
Documentation for it is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat).

My final code ended up something like this:

```
def inception2d(x, in_channels, filter_count):
    # bias dimension = 3*filter_count and then the extra in_channels for the avg pooling
    bias = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3*filter_count + in_channels], mu, sigma)),

    # 1x1
    one_filter = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1, 1, in_channels, filter_count], mu, sigma))
    one_by_one = tf.nn.conv2d(x, one_filter, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

    # 3x3
    three_filter = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, in_channels, filter_count], mu, sigma))
    three_by_three = tf.nn.conv2d(x, three_filter, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

    # 5x5
    five_filter = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, in_channels, filter_count], mu, sigma))
    five_by_five = tf.nn.conv2d(x, five_filter, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

    # avg pooling
    pooling = tf.nn.avg_pool(x, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

    x = tf.concat([one_by_one, three_by_three, five_by_five, pooling], axis=3)  # Concat in the 4th dim to stack
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, bias)
    return tf.nn.relu(x)
```